# BorderLayout Duplicates Button

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, border-layout

I am trying to create a canvas in which I can paint,and a button which resets the canvas in an empty state.
However using BorderLayout my button gets duplicated,the second one is an image copy of the first one but still it doesnt look good.
Is there anything wrong in my code and how can it be fixed.

**PaintCanvas.java**

```
import javax.swing.* ;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
class framakryesore extends JFrame {
    PaintCanvas p1 = new PaintCanvas();
    JButton b1 = new JButton ("Reset");
    public framakryesore (){


    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            clearcanvas(p1);
            repaint();
        }
    });

    this.add(b1,BorderLayout.NORTH);            
    this.add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);




}
    public void clearcanvas(PaintCanvas p){
        p.setX(0);
        p.setY(0);
    }
}
public class PaintCanvas extends JPanel {
    private int x = 0 ;
    private int y = 0 ;
    public void  setX(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    public void setY(int y){
        this.y = y;
    }
    public PaintCanvas() {
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        x=e.getX();
        y=e.getY();
        repaint();
        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){

        }


    });

    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        if (x==0 && y==0){
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }
        else
        {
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 30)); 
        g.drawString(".", x, y);
        }

    }


}
```

**PaintCanvasTest.java**

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class PaintCanvasTest {
 public static void main(String args[]){
     framakryesore pikturo = new framakryesore();
     pikturo.setVisible(true);
     pikturo.setSize(640, 480);
     pikturo.setTitle("Pikturo");
     pikturo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (x==0 && y==0){
    super.paintComponent(g);
```

You should always invoke `super.paintComponent()`. It is responsible for clearing the background of the panel before you do your custom painting.

Comment: If I invoke super.paintComponent() normally than the drawing pattern will dissapear dear friend.

Comment: @Lind, It will paint whatever is in the paintComponent() method. If you are trying to do incremental painting then you need a List to keep track of all the things that you want to paint. See the `DrawOnComponent.java` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example that shows how to do this.

Comment: I will make sure to read that example.Could you tell me anything regarding my problem above,or does it work fine for you?

Comment: @Lind, I did tell you the solution to the problem in my original answer and in my comment I suggested what you need to do to get it working properly. On second thought, maybe the `DrawOnImage` solution is a better solution. Try them both so you understand the differences.